# Is there a way to define multiple implicit evidences via a single HList?

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

I have a piece of code, conceptually similar to the following one:

```
//library code
trait Support[K, V]

def partialHandler[K, V](key: K, value: V)(implicit ev: Support[K, V]) = ???

//user code
implicit val intIntSupport = new Support[Int, Int] {}
implicit val intStringSupport = new Support[Int, String] {}
...

partialHandler(1, "foo)
partialHandler(1, 1)
```

I wonder if there is a way to let users of this library define supported `(K, V)` types more elegantly, e.g.:

```
val supportedTypes = new Support[Int, Int] {} :: new Support[Int, String] {} :: HNil
```

(In essence, I'm looking for an implicit conversion from pretty much unknown HList to `Support[K, V]`. This doesn't look doable, but maybe I'm missing something.)

Answer (score 3):

Try to make `supportedTypes` implicit

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Selector
import shapeless.{HList, HNil}

// library code
trait Support[K, V]

object Support {
  implicit def mkSupport[L <: HList, K, V](implicit l: L, sel: Selector[L, Support[K, V]]): Support[K, V] = null
}

def partialHandler[K, V](key: K, value: V)(implicit ev: Support[K, V]) = ???

//user code
implicit val supportedTypes = new Support[Int, Int] {} :: new Support[Int, String] {} :: new Support[Long, Double] {} :: HNil

partialHandler(1, "foo")
partialHandler(1, 1)
partialHandler(1L, 1.0)
// partialHandler("foo", "bar") // doesn't compile
```

Comment: For sanity's sake, I feel like you'd want to use a wrapper class `case class Supports[L <: HList](supports: L)`.

Comment: @HTNW Yeah https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58784157/revisions