# Is there a way to derive implicits for each member of an HList from Scala Shapeless?

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

I've tried the following:

```
type Params = String :: Int :: HNil

implicit val params: Params = "hello" :: 5 :: HNil

// Supposed to create an implicit for string and int if needed
implicit def meberImplicit[A](
  implicit 
  params: Params,
  selector: Selector[Params, A]
): A = params.select[A]

// Summoning a string
implicitly[String]    // compile-time error
```

However, I'm getting a diverging implicit error:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type String
```

Am I missing something here? And maybe there already is a built-in or better way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779756/is-there-a-way-to-define-multiple-implicit-evidences-via-a-single-hlist/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are *way too generic*:

```
implicit def memberImplicit[A](
  implicit // what you put here is irrelevant
): A = ...
```

With that you basically provided implicit for *any value*. This clashed with any other implicit you defined, as well as with any implicit parameter that you need to fetch.

But let's ask why compiler cannot prove that you just cannot provide the implicits that you pass into `memberImplicit` for bad cases, and so it won't consider it a viable alternative, ans so it would be able to prove that this branch of derivation should be cut (where you don't intent it), ambiguity is resolved, then cake.

Thing is, that the type you are returning is `A`. Which means that even if you added some constraint there like e.g. `A =:!= Params` - while normally it would work... you just provided all these implicits, so type constraints stopped working, and suddenly derivation for things like e.g. `Selector[Params, String]` have more that one way of being instantiated. In that situation virtually any implementation you'll try - as long as it returns `A` - will fail.

In order for things to work you HAVE TO constrain the output to be something that won't match everything - as a matter of the fact, the less it match the better. For instance create a separate type-class for extracting values from the HLists:

```
trait Extractable[A] { def extract(): A }
object Extractable {
  implicit def extractHList[H <: HList, A](
    implicit
    h: H,
    selector: Selector[H, A]
  ): Extractable[A] = () => selector(h)
}

def extract[A](implicit extractable: Extractable[A]): A = extractable.extract()
```

and then

```
extract[String] // "hello"
```

Comment: `Error: value extract is not a member of type parameter H`
`selector(h.extract())`

Comment: Try now, I accidentally left there one line from the older attempt

Comment: I see. I've always suspected that it has something to do with the return type. Thanks.